# AJAX переход по страницам

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

В общем решил я сделать, чтобы менялась только центральная часть сайта, т.е. при нажатии на ссылку например "http://site.ru/fb.php" с помощью js блокируется переход по странице, далее делается запрос через аякс на пхп файл, который открывает ту страницу и запоминает её хтмл код, но открывает с параметром, т.е. "fb.php?js". А там уже проверка если этот параметр присутствует, то не надо подгружать шапку, футер и т.д., только контент. и потом с помощью js менять содержимое блока с контентом. У меня такой вопрос: можно ли сделать прогресс бар при подгрузки контента, чтобы прям в процентах был? И ещё это лучше чем обычный переход, или есть какие-то недостатки, у меня всё правильно спроектировано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спроектировано правильно, единственное что ты забыл про запись в историю ajax-овых ссылок(вертикальных), что в результате приведёт к неправильной работе навигации в браузере, для старых обозревателей ссылки записываются в хеш с дальнейшим отслеживанием его изменения, для новых используй pushState и событие popstate.
На счёт процентов(тут я сам не знаю) если и можно, то только на html5, но смысла особого в этом не вижу, потому как лично у меня в движке запросы занимают в среднем 150ms.
Особых недостатков при такой организации как у тебя не будет, поисковики будут спокойно индексировать контент, только события на подгруженые элементы(в том числе и ajax-ссылки) придётся назначать заново(если юзаешь jquery используй функцию live вместо bind), из плюсов - уменьшатся время обновления контента и загрузка сервера.

Comment: Спасибо, т.е. нужно при переходе на страницу ссылку обновлять, например перешёл со страницы index.php на страницу fb.php, то в браузерной строке сделать так, чтобы было http://site.ru/index.php#fb.php и в таком случаи при нажатии в браузере назад/вперёд будет происходить правильное действие? + Я забыл ещё указать, что при заходе на страничку можно сохранять контент в переменную, а при повторном заходе на эту страничку уже не грузить ajax`ом - вот это как правильнее сделать?

Comment: в браузерах есть локальное хранилище, я лично им не пользовался и вообще у меня это в далёких планах, поэтому и советовать ничего не буду, но по идее тебе нужно будет создать объект в котором имя свойства будет таким же как и ссылка к контенту, и тогда ты без проблем сможешь сделать проверку на предотвращение повторной загрузки

Comment: Ясно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

1) На сколько я знаю, без ActiveScript (Flash) это невозможно. Могу ошибаться.
1.1) Посмотрите в сторону синхронной загрузки, может там есть решение.
2) Ajax не предусматривает использование для подгрузки целых страниц, он создавался для передачи запросов маленькими порциями. Поэтому использовать его в качестве тотального прелоадера — вопрос весьма спорный.

Comment: буэ. ниачем. без обид.

Answer (score 0):

Копайте в сторону history handler, можно как мне кажется двумя способами, ловить get и из него формировать запрос к аякс, далее подключить историю, и обновлять хедер необходимым хэшем, эти параметры можно передавать через например дата атрибуты